# Reparameterizing the multivariate normal model in Bayesian atatistics, Jacobian of the covariance variance matrix?

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-normal-distribution

For the multivariate normal model in Bayesian statistics, where the sampling distribution is $y|\theta,\Sigma \sim N_n(\theta, \Sigma)$, and $\theta$ is a n-dimensional vector, and $\Sigma$ a n by n covariance-variance matrix, I'm trying to re-parametrize the $\Sigma=\Psi^{-1}$. I'm having troubles with finding the Jacobian of $\Psi^{-1} $. How do I find it and what is the answer?